# A question about a homomorphism of kernels of homomorphism of abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to B$ be two homomorphisms of abelian groups.

Suppose that we have a morphism $h:A\to C$.

**Is it true that $h$ induces a homomorphism $\ker f\to \ker g?$**

If not, under what condition(s) can we have such homomorphism?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your question should be (Otherwise we could just take the zero map and say: Yes, we have...):

Is it true that $h$ induces a morphism $\operatorname{ker} f \to \operatorname{ker} g$?

The answer is: We need $f=g \circ h$ to conclude this.

Comment: Dear @MooS. Thank you for your answer. I have another question if you don´t mind: If we take $g:C\to D$ and have a morphism $i:B\to D$, is it true that $h$ still induces a morphism $\ker f\to \ker g$? Apparently we need that the obvious square commutes.

Comment: Yes, the square must commute.

Answer (score 1):

You always have the zero map, independently on any other consideration.

If you want a non-zero map, then here there is the canonical approach. If $g\circ h=f$, then there is a morphism $\mathsf{ker}(f)\to \mathsf{ker}(g)$ given by the (co)restriction of $h$ to the kernels. Explicitly, since for every $a\in \mathsf{ker}(f)$ we have $g(h(a))=f(a)=0$, it follows that $h(a)\in\mathsf{ker}(g)$. In general, there's nothing more you can say *a priori*. For example, take $A=B=C$, $g=\mathsf{Id}_C=h$ and $f$ the zero map.